# Facebook App events not working for iOS 14

Tags: ios, facebook, analytics

I can't see any event in TestEvents Tab and even I set `SDKSettings.enableLoggingBehavior(.AppEvents)` to see debug logs but unfortunately I can't see anything on device console as well

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {    
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {          
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )
        return true
    }
}
```

I have added all required keys in plist as well but can't see any event for iOS